# Logical solution for nested for loop

Tags: perl

I have a bit of logic drain. I hope I can explain what I am missing and what I want in a coherent manner. Let me know if I have to add a bit more data or information.

I have an Excel spreadsheet which I am trying to load to a database. I have slurped the data into an array of hashes. The data in the array looks like this

```
$hash_of_excel = [
    {
        col1 => 'value1',
        col2 => 'value2',
        col3 => 'value3|value4',
        col4 => 'value5|value6|value7',
    },
    {
        col1 => 'value8',
        col2 => 'value9',
        col3 => 'value10|value11|value12',
        col4 => 'value13|value14|value15',
    },
    {
        col1 => 'value16|value17',
        col2 => 'value19|value18',
        col3 => 'value20',
        col4 => 'value21',
    }
]
```

I have a piece of code that walks this data structure to get the values

```
foreach my $results ( @$hash_of_excel ) {
    for my $colname ( sort keys %$results ) {
        my @array = split /\|/, $results->{$colname};
        foreach my $value ( @array ) {
            warn $results->{'col1'}, $results->{'col2'}, $results->{'col3'};
            last;
        }
    }
    last if $counter++ == 2;
}
```

This would result in the same value printing over and over for the number of columns present in each hash (ie 4 in our case).

How can I access different columns for the `DBI` insert but without having to go through lot of for loops?

Is there a way to check if the value has more than one value and pushing them to array instead of having to get all of them in an array?

Or is this good to hand the database inserts to a subroutine and pass just the required column values in an array?

Comment: I'm confused about what your data structure represents. I'm assuming each element in the array represents a row in your spreadsheet, and each key/value pair represents a cell; are you really storing pipe-delimited strings like `value3|value4` in your spreadsheet, or are you trying to represent something else with this?

Comment: [Crossposted at PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1116546).

Comment: @choroba: I have complained about cross-posting on Stack Overflow in the past, and was reprimanded for it. It seems that cross-posting is fine here.

Comment: Please explain what database structure you want to create from this array of hashes. Your code is mostly correct, but as Choroba has pointed out the contents of the innermost `foreach` don't use the control variable `$value`, which is why your output is repeated.

Comment: @Borodin: I don't complain about crossposting, I complain about not informing about it. It's polite to announce crossposting, so people not attending both sites don't waste their time solving a problem already solved at the other end of the Internet.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what exactly you want, but your innermost loop is weird: it iterates over `@array` with `$value`, but `$value` isn't used in it - that's why you're getting the same output for all the iterations.

The following loop outputs all the values instead:

```
foreach my $value (@array){
    warn $value;
}
```

i.e. no `$results`, no `last`.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the note about cross-posting Apologies.